# How do scraping in javascript websites and form required routes?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, screen-scraping

Crawling a html page is a relatively simple task: the crawler needs to identify the "a" tags and follow the href attributes, and there are several tools that do this.

1. But, what about when the site has navigation triggered by javascript?

```
    <a href="#" onClick="some callback here">Link</a>
```

2. And when the site has routes that require the completion of one/several form field(s)?

```
    <input type="text" name="required-input-to-action"></input><button id="">Some Action</button>
```

I'm looking for solutions that allow automatically identifying routes associated with navigation via javascript (case 1) and automatically identifying routes that require parameters filled in by form (case 2) on a site whose structure is not previously known.

I think that to deal with these situations it would be necessary a tool that simulates user interaction with links and forms (including filling out forms) or some kind of solution that analyzes the javascript code (seems less viable given the infinite possibilities). A headless browser could easily do this on a well-known website, but how do you do this on an unfamiliar website?

Are there currently libraries/tools/techiniques that can help me deal with these situations?